# Google Maps Geocoding - Results in different order

Tags: json, xml, geocode

Trying to get the state from maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml is not working for me because not all results are in the same order

The problem is not all locations are the same, I'm using coordinates as the parameter in the urls, most are address_component[5], but the others put the state any and ever where else. The only thing that seems consistant is the formatted address.

See these 2 examples, the states are in different order
for one $xml->result->address_component[5]->short_name is the state
for the other $xml->result->address_component[4]->short_name is the state

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=38.7811981,-75.6823615&sensor=false

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=36.370791599999996,%20-76.75601170000002&sensor=false

There has to be a simple answer! Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just trying to pull the state, how can I when the results are in different order?